# How to use MVC domain model in a 4 layer project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oop, design-patterns, architecture, model

I have a 4 layers(project) Solution.

1. Entity Framework Layer (EFL)
2. Data Access Layer(DLL): All of CRUD operations and queries.
3. Business Logic Layer(BLL): Calling DLL methods and adding some business to them.
4. MVC Layer

As I said I have a separate EFL layer and because of this I don't know How can I use **benefits of models** in MVC? for example I can't write validation Annotations like `<required>` or `<Display(Name:="username:")>` in EFL layer because probably they will delete if I generate model from database again. and even if I do that How I can use Model folder of MVC?

If I create some class same as EFL classes I need to write a huge bunch of code to convert these classes to each other.

As what structure I can use MVC Models? and combine them with Entity Framework classes?

Comment: Yes you need to write Model classes in Model folder

Answer (score 1):

The M in MVC is to me the view model. This means it contains the entities that are used in your views (which are optimized for those views); which are constructed in the controllers based on the entities you receive from your business layer, and which can look completely different than the view model entities.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the following questions:

- How likely is it that you will change EF for some other persistence/ORM mechanism?
- How likely is it that you will change to, or want to add another front-end technology?

If your answers are that those changes are likely, then you need to isolate framework-specifics. You might do this by having a series of base classes with the framework-neutral concepts in and then having framework-specific derivatives that can be added or removed as needed. E.g. `EfCustomer` or `HibernateCustomerRepository`.

If those changes are not likely, then I would question the value that a layered approach actually provides and I wouldn't be too concerned about decorating classes with framework-specific concepts. I would aim to keep things as simple and DRY as possible.